# Import DATA from an SQL server database with identities column

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I would like to export all the data from a database to a new one with SQL Server Manager studio.

I used import and export assistant (taks -> export data) but after the import when I try to save new data

I have insertion error due to identity column error when I try to insert data:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Unable to insert null value in column 'id'

Although I specified to keep identity insert before the export.

I would like to export data in a new database with all the Identities column constraints.

Comment: Doesn't the error message tell you to `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` ? What is the *actual* error? Does it complain about *duplicate* key values perhaps?

Comment: the error message say : 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Unable to insert null value in column 'id'

Comment: That's even clearer then. You're trying to insert a `NULL` into a field that doesn't accept NULLs. This has nothing to do with IDENTITY values at all. Perhaps the CSV has dirty data. Perhaps some fields in the target table are non-nullable

Comment: I get the error from a springboot app. The field  is supposed to accept NULL as  it is an ID with   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY). the error come from the database when iit is export it don't export Identity column constraints.

Comment: The error clearly says that the field does NOT accept NULLs. This isn't affected by the client application, nor the use of `IDENTITY`. The field is declared `NOT NULL`. `IDENTITY` isn't a constraint, it's a method for generating values

Comment: Besides, allowing NULLs in the primary key column makes little sense and simply isn't allowed. `NULL` isn't a value, it means there's no value at all. It can't be used to uniquely identify a row, which is the job of the Primary Key constraint

Comment: Tanhk you for your help, the problem wasn't clear. I actually needed to export an azure database to a SQL server database. I used another  export process :  https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip140.html and now the exported local database is working.

Comment: The error is clear. The question is not. The only way a "different export process" would produce different results is for the original to produce bad/incompatible data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move all data completely from a database. Task->Export is one Option(since the issue which you face is not clear) you can try other option to take backup(.bak file) and restore it to the new database.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your help, the problem wasn't clear.

I actually needed to export an azure database to a SQL server database.

I used another export process : microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip140.html and now the exported local database is working

Comment: That's not a data export process. That extracts the entire database as a script, and *modifies* the target database to match the source. That's not what you asked. It also verifies that the source and target tables were different. In that case, a backup is an easier solution